# How to generate random numbers without repetition in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to generate random numbers to use them as index and i need the generated number to be within a range and cannot be repeated. Is there a predefined function in Flutter to do that or am i going to create my own function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the Random class and then use a `Set` because unlike `List` you don't need to do any extra checking for duplication as `Set` itself won't allow any duplicated element.

for example:

```dart
Set<int> setOfInts = Set();
setOfInts.add(Random().nextInt(max));
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you could simply create a simple shuffled list of index and use removeLast() on it each time you need a new value.

```
var randomPicker = List<int>.generate(n, (i) => i + 1)..shuffle();

...

int random1 = randomPicker.removeLast();

int random2 = randomPicker.removeLast();

assert(random1 != random2);
```

Where n is your maximum index.

Comment: Damn this is so elegant. U algo master

Answer (score 0):

Use [random](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.24.3/dart-math/Random-class.html) from math library:

```
import 'dart:math';
Random random = new Random();
int random_number = random.nextInt(100); // from 0 up to 99
```

And if you want to change minimum number you can use below trick, it will select from 10 up to 99:

```
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(90) + 10;
```

If you need multiple you can add those numbers to list and check them if there is exist with contain, such as:

```
List<int> numberList=[];
Random random = new Random();
for (var i = 0; i == 10; i++){
  int random_number = random.nextInt(100);
  if (!numberList.contains(random_number)) {numberList.add(random_number);}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Lunedor, is there something that i should add in order to avoid repetition of generated numbers?

Comment: Edited my answer, I am not able to try the code right now, sorry if there is some minor mistakes but I think it will give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using all the codes above but none solved my problem.

I created this and it worked for me:

```dart
class Utils {

  static final _random = Random();
  static final Set<int> _setOfInts = {};

  static int randomUnique({required limit}) {
    debugPrint("limit: $limit ---> ${_setOfInts.length} ${_setOfInts.toString()}");
    int randomInt = _random.nextInt(limit) + 1;

    if (_setOfInts.contains(randomInt)) {
      return randomUnique(limit: limit);
    } else {
      _setOfInts.add(randomInt);
      return randomInt;
    }
  }
}
```